# How do I cause my test to fail when a method doesn't exist, using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 application.  I have created this worker class

class PrinterWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

```
def perform
  ...
  service = PrinterService.new(args)
  service.printtt
  ...
end
```

I'm using rspec to unit test my worker.  I have these specs ...

```
RSpec.describe PrinterWorker, :type => :worker do
  context "#perform" do
    let(:printer_service) { instance_double("PrinterService") }
    ...

    context "calls perform successfully" do
      before do
        ...
        allow(PrinterService).to receive(:new).and_return(printer_service)
        allow(printer_service).to receive(:printtt)
        ...

        subject.perform
      end

      it "makes proper service calls" do
        ...
        expect(printer_service).to have_received(:printtt).once
      end
```

The issue I discovered is that if the service "PrinterService" has no "printtt" method, this spec will pass just fine.  That seems wrong to me.  I feel like the spec should fail if I'm trying to invoke a method that doesn't exist.  However, I'm not sure how to configure my test differently to make this happen.

Comment: Is `verify_partial_doubles` set in your configuration or somewhere else? If not, you can explicitly set it to true. It'll make your test fail if you try to mock methods that aren't defined in the object given.

Comment: I didn't know about that.  That solved my problem.